# If I define a pointer pointing to a smart pointer, does this eliminate the advantages of smart pointer?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, pointer-to-pointer

C++ smart pointer: if in a class, I define a pointer pointing to a smart pointer, does this eliminate the advantages of smart pointer? (Note, I didn't say I want to apply this kind of usage)

Like:

```
class TestClass
{
    public SmartPt* ptr1;
}
```

Here SmartPt is the smart pointer class.

Because if I do not manage the pointer well, the pointed smart pointers will not be managed too.

So does this mean it is not a good practice to use a pointer pointing to a smart pointer?
So it is better to directly use the smart pointer, like:

```
public SmartPt object1;
```

[Update 1] To not distract the reader, previously I use MySmartPt, here I replace it with SmartPt.

Comment: Can you post code of how you "define a pointer pointing to a smart pointer" ?

Comment: There might be corner cases where you need such pointers to smart pointers but I'm having a hard time thinking of a realistic application.  Can you show us some code where you've deemed the use of such a pointer useful?

Comment: @5gon12eder, No, I don't specifically want to use it. I just see the code, and think I can I revise it.

Comment: I don't see why you need to make a new smart pointer class.

Comment: @Eric. OK, this is a wrapped one. Off the topic. In this example we could only use the regular smart pointer as an example. I just want to confirm we do not need to use a pointer to a smart pointer.

Comment: I can understand using references (lvalue or rvalue) to smart pointers in an argument list, but I see no reason you would ever have a pointer to a smart pointer.

Comment: @user1914692 The problem is that we cannot see the code you can see.  But the answer is probably no.  Just use the smart pointer itself.  That's what it's there for.

Comment: @5gon12eder, thanks for your confirmation with my point. This is what I meant in my post.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not try to use a pointer to a smart pointer like in the example you are sharing.

smart pointers in C++ are built around RAII principles which try to get rid of the * operator as much as possible. They also use copy/assignment overloading which raw pointers do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

So if you mean doing something like this:

```
void * vptr;
int i = 1346;

std::shared_ptr<int> sptr = std::make_shared<int>(i);

vptr = &sptr;
```

Then the shared pointer will delete itself once it goes out of scope, because, that is what it is supposed to be doing. Smart pointers do not keep references of pointers to them, only references of smart pointers to their data.

Also, if you call `delete vptr;` one of two things will happened:

1. The smart pointer is going to be very mad that it had delete called.
2. If the smart pointer is out of scope then the `vptr` is pointing to an invalid block of memory.